# semivariogramm - manual calculation

Tags: variogram

I have a graph with some data points:

[image]

From these data points I have created a table and calculated the Euclidean distance for each combination.

[image]

Now, I would like to calculate the semi variances for each combination. How do I proceed?

**EDIT**:

The expected results are shown in table below, however:
[image]

Comment: For [well1-well2] pair: Difference = 120 - 103 = 17. Variance = 17^2 = 289. Semivariance = 289/2 = 144.5.

Comment: Thats what I also thought. Maybe I am asking wrong question. I have added the expected results. How do i obtain the semivariances for distances between wells and location?

Comment: Oh, ok... I failed the test... :) It seems the last part is based on a Linear model (semivariance = 4.0 * h) but I do not know how to come up with those numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to derive the value of 4?

Comment: I'd just plotted semivariance vs. distance by Ms-Excel. From the posted `Table 5.12` I took the second table (Distance) as x, and the third table (Semivariances) as y. Then added a fitting curve, which returned y=4*x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example comes from the book [Statistics and Data Analysis in Geology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471172758) (3rd ed. 2002, by John C. Davis) pp. 422, Figure 5-95:

[image]

and it is specified that:

> We will assume that a prior structural analysis bas produced the experimental semivartogram and model shown in Figure 5-96; the model is linear with a slope of 4.0 m2 /km within a neighborhood of 20 km. Values of the semivariance corresponding to distances between the wells are also given in Table 5-15; these may be read directly off the semivariogram or calculated from the slope.

[image]

Therefore the semivariances for distances between wells and location p are calculated by `semivariance = 4 * distance` as Kazuhito says.